# Error Mixed mode assembly against version 'v2.0.50727' .. when creating tables while running setup , Installer class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have window application,have made some `custom action`, Edit `userinterface`  retrieving values from user while installing application and further in installer class while creating tables am getting below error message

```
Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot
be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.
```

I google a lot and found that adding below will solve problem *(Not worked for me)*

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
```

previously my app.confg look like

```
<startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
```

Code : Installer1.cs

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);
            string targetDirectory = Context.Parameters["targetdir"];
            string servername = Context.Parameters["dbservername"];
            string dbname = Context.Parameters["dbname"];
            string strconnectionstring = "Data Source='" + servername + "';Initial Catalog='" + dbname + "';Integrated Security=True";

            if (servername == "")
            {
                throw new InstallException("You did not Specify SQL Servername!");
            }

            else if (dbname == "")
            {
                throw new InstallException("You did not specify the database name!");
            }

            string exePath = string.Format("{0}abc..exe", targetDirectory);
            System.Configuration.Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
            conf.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["abc"].ConnectionString = strconnectionstring;
            conf.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);


            using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(strconnectionstring))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                string getScript = "Use " + dbname + "; CREATE TABLE supportContacts ( id int identity primary key,  type varchar(20),  details varchar(30)  )";
               // string strscript = getScript;
                Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(con1));
                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(getScript );
                con1.Close();
            }   


        }
```

While debugging i get to know error occur at
`server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(strupdatescript);`

Comment: Just get rid of `supportedRuntime` and leave `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"</startup`  otherwise target all references to the same version

Comment: @Ramhound: still getting same error

Answer (score 1):

For me the following worked:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: thank you for reply, well i already tired this, u can check i already mention in my question, dont whats the problem its not  working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same EXACT issue. If anyone can bring to light what could resolve this, most appreciated.

I found the/an answer :). Worked for me.

http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/